# Express+mongoose: Populate data from array of object

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, handlebars.js, mongoose-schema

I am trying to send name and one array as a response to handlebar page.

I want to display data in a table,

**Mongoose Model**

```
const Bank = new Schema({
  sBankName: String,
  sBranch: [
    {
      sBranchName: String,
      sBranchDetail: String,
    }
  ],
  sBankDetail: String,
  dCreatedDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  updated_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

**Router to get page**

```
router.get("/branch_data", isAdminOnly, ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  var sBranch = [];
  Bank.find({})
    .populate("sBranch")
    .exec(function(err, Bank) {
      //var Bankf = JSON.stringify(Bank,null,"\t");
      for (var i = 0; i <= Bank.length; i++) {
        sBranch.push(Bank[i]);
      }
    });
  console.log(sBranch);
  res.render("branch_data", {
    user: req.user,
    admin: req.user.eUserType,
    sBranch: sBranch
  });
});
```

**branch_data.handlebars**

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>No.</th>
         <th>Bank</th>
         <th>Branch Name</th>
         <th>Branch Detail</th>
         <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      {{sBranch}}
      {{#each sBranch}}
      <td>1</td>
      <td>{{this.sBankName}}</td>
      {{#each this.sBranch}}
      <td>{{this.sBranch.sBranchName}}</td>
      {{/each}}
      <td>{{this.sBranch}}</td>
      <td>
         <textarea cols="50" rows="1" class="form-control" readonly></textarea>
      </td>

      </tr>
      {{/each}}
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to get BankName, BranchName and Branchdetail from the database and want to print in a table where one bank can have multiple branches.

can anyone suggest the best way to do this?

Comment: That's an incorrect use of `Populate`, it's used to reference documents in other collections. `sBranch` is part of Bank Schema/Collection.

Comment: can you give an example of that

Comment: And example of what exactly? Have you looked up the documentation, it's usually quite informative. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close. Two issues:

1. Incorrect usage of `.populate()`.

If your schema was defined as:

```
const Bank = new Schema({
  sBankName: String,
  sBranch: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'SomeOtherSchema'
  }],
  sBankDetail: String,
  dCreatedDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  updated_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

Then you would need to call `.populate('sBranch')` which will give you the full `sBranch` object. Otherwise it would just give you and `ObjectId`.

2. Your call to `res.render` will execute **BEFORE** your mongoose query is complete. This will result in the `sBranch` array you defined to always being empty. `async-await` example given below with error handling omitted:

-

```
router.get("/branch_data", isAdminOnly, ensureAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
  // This is already an array. No need to loop and add to another array.
  const sbranch = await Bank.find({}).exec();

  res.render("branch_data", {
    user: req.user,
    admin: req.user.eUserType,
    sBranch: sBranch
  });
});
```